# mongoose CRUD errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

A CRUD operation in mongoose follows the callback pattern:

operation({query}, options, function(error, result) { //callback code})

The problem I'm having is handling errors like unique index violations, etc. For example, if I try to create a record that already exists, the error returned is just a string, like:

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: pcr.users.$agency_id_1_user_id_1  dup key: { : 1000, : "test" }
```

This is all one big string, that I'd rather not have to parse.  Is there a way to get the Mongoose driver to bubble up the actual mongoDB error object?  It is a proper error object that has an error code, error text, etc.

Comment: In my experience, the error passed to the callback _is_ an object, not a string.

Comment: @JohnnyHK when I examine error in the callback, it's just a string. The same error in the mongo native Node.js driver is a proper object with a code property, a message property, etc.

Comment: How are you examining it?

Comment: As I normally do, in a debugger, like Chrome dev tools.  When I examine the MongoDB error it is a an object with several properties.  When I look at the mongoose error object, it has a single property, which is just a big string like in my question

Comment: Weird.  When I tried this yesterday I got an object from Mongoose that I could access the error code as `error.code`.  This was with a `create` call, is that what you're using?  Are you using the latest Mongoose?

Comment: This was with a save call on a new document.  I'm using MOngoose 3.6.11

Comment: Works fine for me with `save` as well with Mongoose 3.6.20.

Comment: Maybe I need to upgrade, here is the exact error I just got from a unique index violation: 

    "MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: pcr.users.$agency_id_1_user_id_1 dup key: { : 1000, : "testes" }"

This was the contents of the 1st argument in my callback function, called "error"

Comment: That's just the `toString()` output you'll get from the `MongoError` object, but it really is an object, not a string.